# simple if condition not working in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, for-loop, vba

```
For Row = row_start To l1 + row_start
    For Column = col_start To l2 + col_start
        If Cells(Row, Column).Value = Cells(2, Column).Value Or Cells(Row, Column).Value = Cells(Row, 2).Value Then
            Cells(Row, Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next Column
Next Row
```

This is a part of the macro I am executing. My Row variable runs from 5 to 33 and Column variable runs from 6 to 34. I have value of 824.6 in AA6 and also in AA2. Similarly, 824.8 in AB7 and AB2. 825 value in AC8 and AC2. And so on.. But, only AC8 is being colored red and not others. I don't understand where the mistake is. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...have you stepped through the macro using F8 ?

Comment: yes I did.. the code just skips the if condition as though it were not true..

Comment: ...and what were the values of the criteria when it skipped and you expecetd it to enter the IF - did you use the Immediate window to check ?

Comment: it shows the same value for both..

Comment: ....and what happens if you doa formula in the speadsheet like this `=A1=A2` to compare these two cells that you think are the same value - does it say True or False?

Comment: at that point in the program please try `?Cells(Row, Column).Value`, `?Cells(2, Column).Value` and `?Cells(Row, Column).Value = Cells(2, Column).Value` in the immediate window - do they return `x,x,TRUE` ?

Comment: It shows x,x False.. but in the excel sheet, when i try =AA2=AA6, it shows TRUE..

Comment: I used Round() function before entering the values into the cells and now it works! But, I don't understand why it didn't work before and why one way shows true and other way shows false for comparison..

Comment: glad you found a work-around

Answer (score 0):

Are those values *exactly* what you state they are, or are they displayed rounded?

The `Value` property will use the actual values in the cells, not their displayed value. Hence `824.6` and `824.5999` formatted with one decimal are *different* values.

Best bet is to put up a message box (or a formula somewhere) with the difference between the suspect cells.

For example, in the following sheet, A1 is `824.6` and B1 is formatted as number with one decimal and set to `824.5999`. C1 is formatted general and set to `=a1-b1`:

```
      A       B       C
1   824.6   824.6   1E-04
```

As to how to fix that (if it's the problem), I believe the `Text` property of a cell is what gets displayed on the screen. If you use that, it should take into account cell formats and so on.

You can also use something like:

```
MsgBox "diff = " & CStr(Range("b1").Value - Range("a1").Value)
```

Beyond that, I'd suggest just stepping through the macro with `F8` (step into) and adding the cells to your watchlist so you can see what they are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what `l1` and `l2` in your code?

As a test please replace with hard-coded values and try the following:

```
Sub xxx()

Dim row
Dim column
Dim row_start As Integer
Dim col_start As Integer
row_start = 5
col_start = 6

For row = row_start To 33
    For column = col_start To 34
        If Cells(row, column).Value = Cells(2, column).Value Or Cells(row, column).Value = Cells(row, 2).Value Then
            Cells(row, column).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next column
Next row

End Sub
```

Easiest way to find out what is going on is to place the cursor in the code and hit `F8` then continually hit `F8` stepping through the loops. Add the following two expressions to your `Watch` window so you can monitor their values (without quotes) and hopefully find the cells that are not agreeing with your criteria:

1. "Cells(row, column).Value = Cells(2, column).Value"
2. "Cells(row, column).Value = Cells(row, 2).Value"

Comment: the code works when the number is hard coded.. the numbers are generated by diving a set of numbers by 5.. however, for a different input.. the code marks all the correct cells except for when the decimal part is 0.4..